# How to manage two pip versions in conda?

Tags: python, pip, environment, conda

I am working with conda in Windows. I accidentally installed two versions of pip using `python -m pip install --upgrade pip`

Now when I run `conda list` from the base env:

[image: two pip versions]

While `pip -version` gives pip 10.0.0

If I create a new env with `conda create --name py3 pip` and run `pip --version` I get an ImportError, however `python -m pip --version` works:

[image: pip ImportError]

How can I resolve this?

Comment: Have you use this `conda create --name py3 pip` with pip at the end? you might have create a virtualenv with the name `pip`.

Comment: This provides the exact same result as in the question

Comment: So you are facing this in new environments that you create or the existing ones or both?

Comment: Both. From the base env I can run `pip --version` (or any `pip` command). From any virtual env `pip --version` fails but `python -m pip` works.

Comment: Do you have seperate python installed in your computer?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First of all I tried to replicate your issue and when I updated pip to 10.0.1 using `python -m pip install --upgrade pip`, the command `pip --version` seems to work for me. I suppose it was a bug on version 10.0.0. Now coming to the issue that multiple pip versions are showing up in `conda list` of base, the `<pip>` one is the incorrect one and must be removed.

You can uninstall one of the pip versions

```
pip uninstall pip
```

Now finally run

```
conda install pip -f
```

And violla! Everything is back to normal.
Next time, you can update pip by using

```
conda update pip
```

It is a safer method to update.

## Note:-

In this scenario we have also removed the pip from your python installation as well. If you want to use pip in cmd prompt then simply use `easy_install pip~=10.0.1` in cmd prompt.

Comment: `pip uninstall pip` successfully removed pip 10.0.0. `conda remove pip` failed with `Remove error: This operation will remove conda without replacing it with another version of conda`. Now `conda list` still shows `pip 9.0.1` and running `pip --version` fails as `pip is not recognized...`

Comment: Okay. You are on the right track. Just run `conda install pip -f` and your problem will be solved.

Comment: @user2573644 My previous answer used to work on previous version of conda maybe. But I have edited the answer and now it should work irrespective of your conda version. Cheers.

Comment: @Verdarth Sharma - this works! The only lingering issue is that `conda update pip` does not update to 10.0.0, `pip --version` still shows 9.0.3. What does the `-f` flag do here?

Comment: The thing is conda supports pip 9.0.3 as the latest version, that is why you can't update it to 10.0.1 using conda. `-f` stands for force. We have forced this install using the above command.