# How to uninstall a specific version of pip in anaconda3

Tags: python, pip, anaconda

I just installed two versions of pip in anaconda3 since the 10.0.1 version has some problems

my anaconda list is like the following:

pip 9.0.1 py35_5
pip 10.0.1

and it works well with the 9.0.1.

Now I'm not sure how to uninstall the 10.0.1 version. Is there anybody who could give me any advice. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Cant you just run a `pip uninstall pip`? Also, check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49888717/how-to-manage-two-pip-versions-in-conda)

Comment: @leoschet Thanks a lot. However, the difference is that I am using 9.0.1 instead of 10.0.1. So If I go straight with the command, it will uninstall 9.0.1 and I am not sure how to switch the pip version. I just deleted the 10.0.1 package file folder directly and it worked for me.